# vim takes a very long time to start up

Tags: vim, startup

I'm experiencing a very sluggish startup time with vim as well as other unrelated programs ever since I logged out and logged back in the last time. Following is the startuptime log for vim:

```
> times in msec  clock   self+sourced   self:  sourced script  clock  
> elapsed:              other lines
> 
> 000.005  000.005: --- VIM STARTING ---
> 000.073  000.068: Allocated generic buffers
> 000.168  000.095: locale set
> 000.180  000.012: GUI prepared
> 000.181  000.001: clipboard setup
> 000.188  000.007: window checked
> 000.621  000.433: inits 1
> 000.626  000.005: parsing arguments
> 000.627  000.001: expanding arguments
> 000.637  000.010: shell init
> 000.909  000.272: Termcap init
> 000.942  000.033: inits 2
> 001.031  000.089: init highlight
> 023.418  000.234  000.234: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 023.543  001.811  001.577: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
> 044.397  015.231  015.231: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
> 044.449  025.111  008.069: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/latest/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
> 052.532  000.199  000.199: sourcing /grid/common/pkgsData/vim-v7.3/Linux/RHEL4.0-2007-x86_64/share/vim/vim73/syntax/nosyntax.vim
> 059.858  000.175  000.175: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 059.966  003.842  003.667: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/synload.vim
> 060.002  010.259  006.218: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syntax.vim
> 069.085  000.178  000.178: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 072.326  000.173  000.173: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 076.317  000.175  000.175: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/syntax/syncolor.vim
> 076.477  013.311  012.785: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/colors/desert.vim
> 079.768  000.019  000.019: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/filetype.vim
> 080.322  065.921  017.221: sourcing $HOME/.vimrc
> 080.330  013.378: sourcing vimrc file(s)
> 106.526  000.376  000.376: sourcing /home/haitham/.vim/plugin/genutils.vim
> 111.139  001.435  001.435: sourcing /home/haitham/.vim/plugin/multiselect.vim
> 113.534  000.147  000.147: sourcing /home/haitham/.vim/plugin/omap-param.vim
> 119.245  000.073  000.073: sourcing /home/haitham/.vim/plugin/qfixtoggle.vim
> 122.821  000.696  000.696: sourcing /home/haitham/.vim/plugin/surround.vim
> 172.247  000.098  000.098: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/getscriptPlugin.vim
> 176.387  000.252  000.252: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/gzip.vim
> 179.876  000.183  000.183: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/matchparen.vim
> 182.748  000.620  000.620: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/netrwPlugin.vim
> 186.171  000.051  000.051: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/rrhelper.vim
> 189.739  000.046  000.046: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/spellfile.vim
> 193.406  000.195  000.195: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tarPlugin.vim
> 199.206  000.060  000.060: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/tohtml.vim
> 202.299  000.152  000.152: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/vimballPlugin.vim
> 205.345  000.147  000.147: sourcing /grid/common/pkgs/vim/v7.3/share/vim/vim73/plugin/zipPlugin.vim
> 205.394  120.533: loading plugins
> 12343.581  12138.187: inits 3
> 12349.592  006.011: reading viminfo
> 18421.239  6071.647: setup clipboard
> 18421.264  000.025: setting raw mode
> 18421.270  000.006: start termcap
> 18421.293  000.023: clearing screen
> 18421.504  000.211: opening buffers
> 18421.564  000.060: BufEnter autocommands
> 18421.566  000.002: editing files in windows
> 18425.833  004.267: VimEnter autocommands
> 18425.835  000.002: before starting main loop
> 18426.587  000.752: first screen update
> 18428.334  001.747: --- VIM STARTED ---
```

Apparently the biggest components are "inits 3" and "setup clipboard".

Any clues what to do about it?

Comment: It actually looks like the slow parts are the ones right before "inits 3" and "setup clipboard". That's a big jump in time after "loading plugins". Start vim with "vim -u" to see if it is any faster. Disable one plugin at a time until you find the culprit.

Comment: Tried vim -u vimrc --noplugin (with vimrc being empty). Same startup time, also in "inits 3" and "setup clipboard".

Comment: Try [this](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/profiling-vimscript-performance/) for a more precise profiling.

Comment: How big is your .viminfo file? What is in `set viminfo=`?

Comment: Maye a too Windows like approch, but did you try uninstalling & purging it and reinstalling it?

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski viminfo='100,<50,s10,h

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski my .viminfo file is 40k.

Comment: @Cheiron I'm not even sure it's a vim issue. It happens with other programs too (xev, emacs, etc.) .. I'm experimenting with vim because it's the only I can profile!

Comment: The fact that other programs are taking a long time to start up is a pretty good sign that this has nothing at all to do with vim.  There's no good, easy way to diagnose a generally-slow computer, and it's well beyond the scope of any single Stack Overflow question.

Comment: Let me put it this way: What do the "inits 3" and "setup clipboard" components of the vim startup time mean? That makes it more of a vim question.

Answer (score 125, accepted):

## setup clipboard

First, try running Vim with the following command:

```
$ vim -X
```

You can try using the `-X --startuptime <file>` options together to see if the "setup clipboard" component is still slow.

If `-X` helps, you can get the same effect by adding the following line to your vimrc file:

```
set clipboard=exclude:.*
```

### Explanation

If this helps what is happening is that on startup Vim is trying to connect to an X server to allow it to use the clipboard. The `-X` option tells Vim to not try connecting to the X server. From `:help -X`

```
-X          Do not try connecting to the X server to get the current
            window title and copy/paste using the X clipboard.  This
            avoids a long startup time when running Vim in a terminal
            emulator and the connection to the X server is slow.
            See --startuptime to find out if affects you.
            Only makes a difference on Unix or VMS, when compiled with the
            +X11 feature.  Otherwise it's ignored.
            To disable the connection only for specific terminals, see the
            'clipboard' option.
            When the X11 Session Management Protocol (XSMP) handler has
            been built in, the -X option also disables that connection as
            it, too, may have undesirable delays.
```

The clipboard option can be used to achieve the same thing more permanently via your vimrc file. From `:help 'clipboard'`

> To never connect to the X server use: 
>          exclude:.*
>   This has the same effect as using the -X argument.
>   Note that when there is no connection to the X server
>   the window title won't be restored and the clipboard
>   cannot be accessed.

The `clipboard=exclude:.*` option can be refined to only work with particular terminals, if you want Vim to connect to the X server in some instances. Check out `:help 'clipboard'` for more on this.

For me, this problem was happening because I had "X11 Forwarding" enabled on my ssh client but did not always have an X Server running on the ssh client machine.

When I have an X server running on the target machine, Vim is much faster starting up (though still a bit slow).

In this setup, I want to maintain the X11 Forwarding, but do not need Vim to use the X clipboard, so I added the `set clipboard=exclude:.*` line to my vimrc. Now Vim startup is quick for me once more.

## inits 3

You seem to have already eliminated your plugins/customisations as a possible cause by trying `vim -u NONE` (and you said your vimrc was empty).

I am not familiar with this issue, but as suggested above, it *might* be to do with your viminfo file.

You can determine whether this is the case by starting Vim with the following command:

```
$ vim -i NONE
```

According to `:help slow-start`:

> If you have "viminfo" enabled, the loading of the viminfo file may take a
>   while.  You can find out if this is the problem by disabling viminfo for a
>   moment (use the Vim argument "-i NONE").  Try reducing the number of
>   lines stored in a register with ":set viminfo='20,<50,s10".

Comment: I have the clipboard issue when running a terminal hosted in a windows environment running ClipX - a clipboard manager that has a large history. Now I suspect my vim startup time is proportional to the size and content of the clipboard history.

Comment: This is very good information.  So far afaict you have identified two connections vim makes to the X11 server, get window title and clipboard.  However, it appears that when I run vim it attempts to connect four times.  Do you know what the other two are?

Comment: One additional question: I occasionally use the X11 clipboard register; do you know a way to increase the speed of initializing the X11 connection rather than avoiding it altogether?

Comment: Helps to note as well that replacing whats in your clipboard solved the issue. I believe it was cause it was such a huge text file that I had copied.

Comment: Interestingly, in my case, adding `set clipboard=exclude:.*` at the start of my .vimrc does not change startup times. Starting vim with `-X` is about a one second improvement. I suspect a plugin is changing my clipboard settings, while setting the command line option overrides vimscript changes.

Comment: close the terminal and re-login after adding `set clip...` to your `.vimrc`.

Comment: setting the SESSION_MANAGER env var to an empty value (as suggested in a comment to the `nvim` reply below) solved the issue for me while preserving clipboard functionality.

Comment: Same here with vim 8.1: unsetting SESSION_MANAGER env var solved the slow startup issue while preserving clipboard functionality.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using v7.4. The -X option increase the startup time successfuly when vim compiled with +clipboard. But, since the connection to the X now disabled, we can't copy and paste from x clipboard anymore.

Meanwhile, vim is my only way to write before send it to email, twitter, telegram, etc. So copy+paste from vim is a must. Just found the simple solution :

```
alias v='nvim'
```

Nvim use my old `.vimrc` automatically. clipboard feature work seamlessly without any configuration hassle.

Not provoking to using nvim. I just found it the shortest solution to my problem now.

Comment: Perhaps resetting SESSION_MANAGER to be empty works for you? This preserves copy/pasting for me while getting rid of the delay.